# Vue: display response from form submit on another page

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `<form>` in `vue`. I send that form to server, get a JSON response, print it to console. It works fine.

However I need to take that JSON response and display it on another page. For instance, I have two `.vue` files: `GetAnimal.vue` that has the form and retrieves the animal data from an API and a `DisplayAnimal.vue` that displays animal's data. I need to direct the response animal data from `GetAnimal.vue` to `DisplayAnimal.vue`.

**GetAnimal.vue**:

```
<template>
 <form v-on:submit.prevent="getAnimal()">
  <textarea v-model = "animal"
      name = "animal" type="animal" id = "animal"
      placeholder="Enter your animal here">
  </textarea>

  <button class = "custom-button dark-button"
      type="submit">Get animal</button>
 </form>
</template>
```

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        name: 'App',
        data: function() {
            return {
                info: '',
                animal: ''
            }
        },
        methods:  {
            getAnimal: function()  {
                 axios
                    .get('http://localhost:8088/animalsapi?animal=' + this.animal)
                    .then(response => (this.info = response.data));
                 console.log(this.info);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**response**:
retrieves a JSON with animal data, say like this:

```
{
"fur-color": "yellow",
"population": 51000,
"isExtinct": false,
"isDomesticated": true
}
```

and I now want to give that JSON to a `DisplayAnimal.vue` at `/viewanimal` endpoint:

**DisplayAnimal.vue**:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Animal name: {{animal}}}</p>
    <p>Fur color: {{furColor}}</p>
    <p>Population: {{population}}</p>
    <p>Is extinct: {{isExtinct}}</p>
    <p>Is domesticated: {{isDomesticated}}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

How would I do that? I know I can redirect via `this.$router.push({ path });`, but I've only used it for navigation, while here JSON response needs to be passed. Is this even a correct / good practice way of approaching this?

**EDIT**:

I tried this:

in **GetAnimal.vue** I added this data:

```
data: function() {
   return {
     animal:  {
       name: 'Cat',
       furColor: 'red',
       population: '10000',
       isExtinct: false,
       isDomesticated: true
}
```

and in **DisplayAnimal.vue** this:

```
<script>
    export default  {
        props:  {
            animal:  {
                name: {
                    type: String
                },
                furColor:  {
                    type: String
                },
                population: String,
                isExtinct: String,
                isDomesticated: String
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

and in **GetAnimal.vue** I added this:

```
methods: {
            animals: function()  {
                alert("animals");
                this.$router.push({name: 'viewanimal',
                                query: {animal: JSON.stringify(this.animal)}});
            },
```

to try to display that test animal using the display component. However it just didn't work - I get an empty page.

Comment: The right way to save data like this is using Vuex states

Comment: Why not `$router.push` the form inputs (as queries) to the receiving component and invoke the API there? Otherwise, I'd have to agree with the others here, that this would be best done with Vuex.

Comment: If you want quick solution you can `localStorage.setItem("animal", JSON.stringify(yourdata));` and then you can retrieve with `var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("animal"));` finally remove it with `localStorage.removeItem("animal");` you can read about localStorage here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage . The proper solution would be you starting to use vuex and then you can share data between router components with ease, vuex might sound scary but that's the best option you've got in SPA's.

Comment: @mentorgashi How would it work concurrently though? With several users simultaneously filling the form with a different animal and wanting to see their animal's data? Doesn't `localStorage` work as global / static variables that have only 1 copy / value that are shared everywhere?

Comment: @parsecer localStorage is a browser API (https://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage), and lives just within the device memory. They wont go device cross and get mixed by other user session. Since there's lack of context of what you do, again the fundamental solution to sharing data between components is vuex or state management approach.

Comment: You can start with basics of vuex here https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/mastering-vuex/success-error-notifications very good and thorough explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Using Vuex, you can solve this easily

Working example on netlify
https://m-animalfarm.netlify.app/

code on github
https://github.com/manojkmishra/animalfarm

[image]

GetAnimal.vue ( I have disabled axios call for testing and hardcoded info)

```
 <template>
 <form v-on:submit.prevent="getAnimal()">
   <textarea v-model = "animal" name = "animal" type="animal" id = "animal"
   placeholder="Enter your animal here">
  </textarea>
  <button class = "custom-button dark-button"
  type="submit">Get animal</button>
  </form>
 </template>
 <script>
 import axios from 'axios';
 export default 
 {
    name: 'App',
    data: function() {  return { info: '', animal: ''  }  },
    methods:  {
        getAnimal: function()  {
            // axios
            //   .get('http://localhost:8088/animalsapi?animal=' + this.animal)
             //   .then(response => (this.info = response.data),
                this.info={"fur-color": "yellow","population": 51000,"isExtinct":     
                            false,"isDomesticated": true },
                this.$store.dispatch('storeAnimals', this.info)
                //);
        }
    }
 }
 </script>
```

DisplayAnimal.vue

```
<template>
<div>
<p>Animal name: {{stateAnimal.animal}}</p>
<p>Fur color: {{stateAnimal.furColor}}</p>
<p>Population: {{stateAnimal.population}}</p>
<p>Is extinct: {{stateAnimal.isExtinct}}</p>
<p>Is domesticated: {{stateAnimal.isDomesticated}}</p>
 </div>
</template>
<script>
 import {mapState, mapGetters} from 'vuex';
export default {
computed:{  ...mapState({ stateAnimal:state => state.modulename.stateAnimal }),   
 },
}
</script>
```

modulename.js ( store module)

```
export default
{
 state: {stateAnimal:null,  },
 getters:{ },
 mutations: 
 {    ['STORE_ANIMALS'] (state, payload) 
    {  state.stateAnimal = payload;  
    console.log('state=',state)
   },

  },
 actions: 
 {  storeAnimals: ({commit}, data) => 
    { console.log('storeanim-data-',data);
      commit(  'STORE_ANIMALS', data   );  
    },     
  }
  }
```

Index.js (for vuex store), you can disable persistedstate as its for saving state if page is refreshed

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import modulename from './modules/modulename'
import createPersistedState from "vuex-persistedstate";

Vue.use(Vuex)
export default new Vuex.Store({
plugins: [createPersistedState({ storage: sessionStorage })],
state: {  },
mutations: {  },
actions: {  },
modules: { modulename }
})
```

State is available/shared for all the components
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Should I run the `modulename.js` and `index.js`? Or what should I do with those files? Also, is the `$store.storeAnimals` variable global? As in you said all components have access to it. What if I have two forms on two different pages that the same users fills with different animals simultaneously - those forms should direct to the `DisplayAnimal.vue` pages that would display both animals - but if an animal is stored in the global variable, it gets overwritten, so the same animal would essentially get displayed - the one that got written into the store last?

Comment: Vuex store is included in main.js of vue project like router. I have removed module and included all the vuex code in index.js of store folder on github repo.                                                                                                             yes vuex state variables are global. You are correct- if you store things in same state variable from two forms, it will get updated with latest value. But you can store values from diff form's in diff state variables in case you want them to be separate and they all will be available globally.

Comment: But doesn't the `DisplayAnimal.vue` only looks at the single variable in the `$store` to display? What if I were to open unknown number of forms simultaneously? I'd have to create a separate variable for each? I'm really sorry to say that, but it doesn't seem like a viable solution to me.

Comment: I come from Java and there this was done *very* simply - without any global variables - a `.jsp` or `.html` page took a look at a `HttpRequest` object and took an `attribute` from it: `attribute` was a piece of data associated with that particular request. So the server would just attach say that JSON to the request: `request.setAttribute("animal", animalJsonString);` and the page would `<p>request.get("animal")</p>`.

Comment: That's pseudocode, but you get the gist. It doesn't seem to me like `vue` has attributes like this? But I thought that `vuex` thing worked similarly - and it doesn't - global states in my mind are for different things, app - specific things: like if there was a single animal for the whole app, etc - not request-specific pieces of data - so it looks like my only alternative with vue is passing the animal JSON data as a `GET` or `POST` parameter. And seeing that `GET` parameter's length is limited, it would be a `POST` parameter.

Comment: request.setAttribute("animal", animalJsonString); and the page would <p>request.get("animal")</p>   When you say this I visualize this almost same as vuex state updated and then accessed in other page. When we say global, that means for that instance of users browser.  state is local for one instance of a browser and gets destroyed after refresh/close.

Comment: The request attributes are local - they are attached to individual request. That's it. When a user leaves the page all request data is dead. The vuex is global - all requests share the data in it - that's why it's not suitable. It doesn't really help that it's user-specific storage, it's still global for that user's requests.

Answer (score 1):

well first of all create a second folder call it services and create service.js for you axios call- good practice and cleaner code overall.
second use vuex. this kind of data is best used with vuex.

As far as I understand GetAnimal.vue is the parent component and you wish to display it in the child component DisplayAnimal.vue.
If so and you wish to see if this works just use props.
you can also send that same information or any other information for the child back to the parent using an $emit().
STRONGLY recommended to use vuex in order to manage the state

Comment: Could you show some code? No, `GetAnimal.vue` is as of now is in no way connected to the `DisplayAnimal.vue` - the code I have is the one I've posted. Why would it be parent? I'm thinking in terms of the MVC model where `GetAnimal.vue` is both a controller and a model: the form gets the user's input and updates the model (the animal info: `this.info`). Now it's just about passing that info to the view which is `DisplayAnimal.vue`.

Comment: I'm coming from Java and in Java apps I didn't see view classes extending model/controlling classes - the relationship is usually one of composition rather than inheritance.

Comment: then what is it you want to do? in order to show data in vue from one component to another is using vuex or passing data with props(from parent to child or you can call it siblings) even so using props.

Answer (score 1):

```
Vue.component('product',{
  props:{
    message:{
      type:String,
      required:true,
      default:'Hi.'
    }
  },
  template:`<div>{{message}}</div>`,
  data(){...}
})

//html in the other component you axios call is in this component //<product meesage="hello"></product>
```

Comment: you have 3 options in total in vuejs which are all good depending on your needs
1-Using props to share data from parent to child,
2-Emitting custom events to share data from child to parent,
3-Using Vuex to create an app-level shared state.

Comment: How do I pass the `message` value to that component though? I've read on props already, but what I don't get is how to assign props value from `GetAnimal.vue` to `DisplayAnimal.vue`.

Comment: the component you write "props" in is the receiving and as shown above
you send it from the other one via v-bind
Vue.component('storage', {
  data:{
return{
  message={},//say it gets data via axios call}

},....
})
when you want to show it you want to tell that same product component it`s about to get some props
<template>
  `<div>
    <product v-bind:message="message"/>
//you can also use shorthand just :message="message"
</div>`
</template>
the storage tell product component that it sends message prop with the name of message and inside product component you specify props

Comment: learn the basics and then learn vuex state once you understand vue.

Comment: data(){
 return{
 ... 
}
}
noticed a typo

Answer (score 1):

I would pass the animal name/id as a route param to the display page and have that component responsible for fetching and displaying the relevant animal data. This avoids the situation where a user could visit the display page directly via the URL and see an incomplete page.

In situations where you want to share local state between pages, as others have pointed out you'd probably want to use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).

**EDIT:**

I'm adding some code to my answer as requested by the OP.

*Routes:*

```
const routes = [
  { path: "/", component: SearchAnimals },
  { path: "/viewanimal/:name", component: DisplayAnimal, name: "displayAnimal" }
];
```

*DisplayAnimal.vue:*

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Animal name: {{animal.name}}</p>
    <p>Fur color: {{animal.furColor}}</p>
    <p>Population: {{animal.population}}</p>
    <p>Is extinct: {{animal.isExtinct}}</p>
    <p>Is domesticated: {{animal.isDomesticated}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "DisplayAnimal",
  data: () => ({
    animal: {}
  }),
  methods: {
    fetchAnimal(name) {
      axios
        .get(`http://localhost:8088/animalsapi?animal=${name}`)
        .then(response => {
          this.animal = response.data;
        });
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchAnimal(this.$route.params.name);
  }
};
</script>
```

*SearchAnimals.vue:*

```
<template>
  <form v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <textarea
      v-model="animal"
      name="animal"
      type="animal"
      id="animal"
      placeholder="Enter your animal here"
    ></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Get animal</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "SearchAnimal",
  data: () => ({
    animal: ""
  }),
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      this.$router.push({
        name: "displayAnimal",
        params: { name: this.animal }
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Obviously this is a bare-bones example, so doesn't contain any error handling etc., but it should get you up and running.

Comment: I'd really rather not limit myself that way - maybe later I'd want to get an animal by fur color the user provided: `fur color -> form -> server -> returns animal -> DisplayAnimal.vue -> displaying the animal` while your solution would require `fur color -> form -> server -> returns animal with that fur color -> pass animal name to DisplayAnimal.vue -> server -> returns animal with that name -> displaying the animal`

Comment: I can see that my best bet is to pass data to the `DisplayAnimal.vue` as a HTTP parameter. I was thinking of maybe passing the data as a POST parameter: `animal name/fur/whatever -> form -> server -> returns animal -> GetAnimal.vue creates a POST request with JSON animal as a request parameter -> redirects to the DisplayAnimal.vue with the POST JSON animal parameter being passed to the GetAnimal.vue`. Is that possible to do?

Comment: I suppose it depends on what you're trying to achieve. Given what you've just said, why treat the animal display as a separate route? It would seem to make more sense to query the API and display the returned animal data within the same route.

Comment: But for that I would have to get rid of elements I already have there - the form that takes user input. And what if I later want to display the animal elsewhere? I'd have to repeat the display code? How would you do it in the same page? Somehow remove the form element and replace it with divs that display animal data? What if there are many elements to get rid off on that page ?

Comment: Well, that all depends on your page layout.. you could swap out components, replacing the form with the results, or you opt to display the data alongside the form (probably better UI). If the display code is a component that receives an animal as a prop, then reusing it elsewhere is simple.

Comment: My page layout is exactly the same as I posted in question. Without seeing code I can't say it sounds like a better solution to sending the `animal` object as a parameter to the `DisplayAnimal.vue` component via `router.push`

Comment: And as I said in the question - I want the animal being displayed apart from anything else - nothing other than the animal, no forms, no nothing. So `What if there are many elements to get rid off on that page ?` still stands. It sounds like a hassle to manually delete those other elements from the page and then add the displaying animal code.

Comment: `If the display code is a component that receives an animal as a prop, then reusing it elsewhere is simple. ` I don't understand what you mean by this. You said you want to reuse the existing `GetAnimals.vue` component, instead of using `DisplayAnimal.vue`: `why treat the animal display as a separate route? It would seem to make more sense to query the API and display the returned animal data within the same route.`

Comment: It sounds like you already have your app working in a way that meets your requirements, and it doesn't seem like my suggestion is what you're looking for. Unless you really want to discuss it further, I'm happy to leave it at that :)

Comment: @NilsonJacquers It's not just about getting *my* app working. As the bounty states, I'm looking for a `canonical answer` and several ways of doing this - that is good, request-safe ways that don't use a global storage. If you feel like your way is such, it'd be good to post it to help out future readers.